# tomcat 9 not starting when I include jax dependency java 11

Tags: java, jax-rs, jax-ws, java-11, tomcat9

I have addded below dependencies for my pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

because java 11 need that dependencies separately but then I build my project and start tomcat it is not starting after below line

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/C:/Users/Manoj/Music/tritium-tomcat-9-java-11/lib/ext/xstream-1.3.1.jar) to field java.util.Properties.defaults
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

the stream is provided dependency and it is ok when I remove my Jax dependencies from war tomcat start normally also providing above warnings,
so what can I do for resolve this?

Comment: Those are just warnings (some components aren't entirely version11-compatible), search for more error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this it happens because I used XStream and Jax dependency jars same war file so it reflet with classes I remove xstream and use alternative method after identify issue.